# List of variable size dicts to a dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary, flatten

I couldn't find my exact question when I searched.

I have a dataframe with a lot of columns. In one of the columns each cell has a list of dictionaries. The dictionaries vary in length. Sometimes different dictionaries have keys that are the same. Sometimes they don't.

Here's some example code to show what one cell might be like.

```
list_of_dicts = [{'a':'joe','b':2},{'a':3,'c':4, 'd':5},{'a':6,'c':7,'e':8,'f':9}]

import pandas as pd
mydict = {}
for i in range(len(list_of_dicts)):
    mydict[i] = pd.json_normalize(list_of_dicts[i])

print(mydict)
print(type(mydict))
pd.json_normalize(mydict)
```

And here's the output I get.

```
{0:    a  b
0  1  2, 1:    a  c  d
0  3  4  5, 2:    a  c  e  f
0  6  7  8  9}
<class 'dict'>

    0           1               2
0   a b 0 1 2   a c d 0 3 4 5   a c e f 0 6 7 8 9
```

So what it's doing is coalescing a "0", the keys, and the values all together into the columns named "0", "1", and "2".

What I want to do, though, is one of two things. Either I want to expand the whole list of dictionaries into a single row so that I can include the other data in the row around it OR I want to create one column for each unique key in the list and create multiple data rows with "NaN" where that dictionary didn't have a key value pair.
So my goal is either something like this (column order not really important)

```
a_1          b          c_1          d          e          f          a_2          a_3          c_2
joe          2          4            5          8          9          3            6            7
```

OR something like this

```
             a          b            c          d          e          f
row          joe        2            NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
row          3          NaN          4          5          NaN        NaN       
row          6          NaN          7          NaN        8          9
```

I've played around with pd.json_normalize, flatten_json, Series, and not been able to make anything work in order to end up with a dataframe at the end.

I figure that I could nest some loops and use pd.concat or hstack, but that seems rather clumsy. Is there a good, clean pythonic way to do this?

***Update***
Rather than muddying the waters here I've clarified my question in a different post at [Python dataframe column of lists of dicts into columns with single elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68562456/python-dataframe-column-of-lists-of-dicts-into-columns-with-single-elements).

Comment: `pd.json_normalize(list_of_dicts)`?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)`

Comment: pd.json_normalize
and
pd.DataFrame
work on a single cell.
As I stated at the beginning, though, I want to do this for EVERY cell.