# Python dataframe column of lists of dicts into columns with single elements

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary, flatten

I tried to ask this question in a different format, and I got answers that addressed a specific part of the question but not the whole thing. In an effort not to confuse things I'm trying again and phrasing the question differently.

I have a dataframe where several columns have regular data but one column has, as elements, lists of dictionaries. Here's an example.

```
list_of_dicts = [{'a':'sam','b':2},{'a':'diana','c':'grape', 'd':5},{'a':'jody','c':7,'e':'foo','f':9}]
list_of_dicts_2 = [{'a':'joe','b':2},{'a':'steve','c':'pizza'},{'a':'alex','c':7,'e':'doh'}]

df4.loc[0,'lists_of_stuff'] = list_of_dicts
df4.loc[1,'lists_of_stuff'] = list_of_dicts_2

df4.loc[0,'other1'] = 'Susie'
df4.loc[1,'other1'] = 'Rachel'

df4.loc[0,'other2'] = 123
df4.loc[1,'other2'] = 456

df4
```

```
    other1  lists_of_stuff                                                              other2
0   Susie   [{'a':'sam','b':2},{'a':'diana','c':'grape', 'd':5},{'a':'jody','c':7,'e':'foo','f':9}]                 123
1   Rachel  [{'a':'joe','b':2},{'a':'steve','c':'pizza'},{'a':alex,'c':7,'e':'doh'}]        456
```

I'm trying to split up those dictionaries into columns so that I have a simpler dataframe. Something like this (column order might be different)

```
    other1 a_1   b   a_2   c     d   a_3      c_2   e   f   other2
0   Susie  sam   2   diana grape 5   jody     7     foo 9   123
1   Rachel joe   2   steve pizza NaN alex     7     doh NaN 456
```

or like this

```
    other1 a     b   c     d   e   f   other2
0   Susie  sam   2   NaN   NaN NaN NaN 123
1   Susie  diana NaN 4     5   NaN NaN 123
2   Susie  jody  NaN 7     NaN foo 9   123
3   Rachel joe   2   NaN   NaN NaN NaN 456 
4   Rachel steve NaN pizza NaN NaN NaN 456
5   Rachel alex  NaN 7     NaN doh NaN 456
```

Two thing that ***don't*** work are `pd.DataFrame(df4['list_of_stuff'])` (which just shows the dataframe as it is; i.e. it doesn't change anything) and `pd.json_normalize(df4['list_of_stuff'])` (which throws an error). Additionally, flatten_json and solutions involving Series have not yielded workable results.

What's the right pythonic way to turn df4 into one of the proposed outputs?

(Yes I asked nearly the same question elsewhere. [List of variable size dicts to a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68539200/list-of-variable-size-dicts-to-a-dataframe). That question was unclear, so I decided to try again with a new question rather than adding a bunch of stuff to the other one and making it difficult to understand.)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
# if the lists_of_stuff are strings, apply literal_eval
#from ast import literal_eval
#df["lists_of_stuff"] = df["lists_of_stuff"].apply(literal_eval)

df = df.explode("lists_of_stuff")
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("lists_of_stuff").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   other1  other2      a    b      c    d    e    f
0   Susie     123    sam  2.0    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
0   Susie     123  diana  NaN  grape  5.0  NaN  NaN
0   Susie     123   jody  NaN      7  NaN  foo  9.0
1  Rachel     456    joe  2.0    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  Rachel     456  steve  NaN  pizza  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  Rachel     456   alex  NaN      7  NaN  doh  NaN
```

---

EDIT: To reindex columns:

```py
#... code as above
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).reindex(
    [*df.columns[:1]] + [*df.columns[2:]] + [*df.columns[1:2]], axis=1
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   other1      a    b      c    d    e    f  other2
0   Susie    sam  2.0    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     123
1   Susie  diana  NaN  grape  5.0  NaN  NaN     123
2   Susie   jody  NaN      7  NaN  foo  9.0     123
3  Rachel    joe  2.0    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     456
4  Rachel  steve  NaN  pizza  NaN  NaN  NaN     456
5  Rachel   alex  NaN      7  NaN  doh  NaN     456
```